# Opencart different prices different city

Tags: php, location, opencart, price

I want to implement different price for different city.
Website will for india only. And there will be few city only.

Please help me to achieve this system.

Comment: Do you want to show different prices in product details page based on the users geo location ? Or are you trying to show a dropdown with list of cities in product details page?

Comment: This is not best idea to show different price for different city. But you will implement shipping cost as per city selection. Most of the site doing this idea and his site working well!!

Comment: I want to show different prices in product details page based on the users geo location.